# Visual Studio のプロパティウィンドウで検索かフィルタリング

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2013 を使っているのですが、プロパティが多い場合に
設定項目を探すのが厄介で、検索やフィルタリング機能が無いか探したの
ですが分からなかったので質問させて頂きました。

該当する機能や、拡張機能等があれば教えて頂けないでしょうか？
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるかも。[PropertyGridコントロールの使い方](https://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/control/propertygrid.html), [.NET Framework の PropertyGrid コントロールの高度な活用](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/previous-versions/msdn/architecture-center/cc440113(v=vs.71)), [Make Your Components Really RAD with Visual Studio .NET Property Browser](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/aa302334(v=msdn.10)), [Using Property Grid In C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-property-grid-in-C-Sharp/), [Using PropertyGrid](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22717/Using-PropertyGrid)

Answer (score 0):

プロジェクトのプロパティのことであると仮定してお話します。
構成プロパティの各最上位項目の下にある「全てのオプション」を選択して、画面の最上部の「オプション又はスイッチの検索」エディットボックスにキーワードを入力することによって絞り込めます。
ですが、それほど便利ではありません。
自分も新規ソリューション/プロジェクトを作成する場合はこつこつと一つづつ設定してます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。

申し訳ありません。説明が悪かったですね。

プロジェクトのプロパティでは無く、「Ctrl+W, P」で表示される、
フォームコントロールのプロパティ、イベント（コントロール以外
では別の物が表示される為、一例です）を表示するプロパティウィ
ンドウの事でした。